# Variables set of three?

Tags: python

I'm starting to learn Python from a tutorial and I'm not sure how this bit of code works. So we have a `return` for `jelly_beans, jars, crates` in the function; however, a little below we see a new set of variables named `beans, jars, crates`. Does this mean that `jelly_beans, jars, crates` from the `return` can be replaced with any combo of three? Can someone break this down for me?

```
def secret_formula(started):
    jelly_beans = started * 500
    jars = jelly_beans / 1000
    crates = jars / 100
    return jelly_beans, jars, crates

start_point = 10000
beans, jars, crates = secret_formula(start_point)

print "With a starting point of: %d" % start_point
print "We'd have %d beans, %d jars, and %d crates." % (beans, jars, crates)
```

Comment: It's not clear what you need to have explained.  The variables inside the `def` do not exist outside of it.  The calling function outside the `def` uses similarly named but not identical variable names to capture the values returned from the function invocation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function returns a `tuple`

```
return jelly_beans, jars, crates
```

or more explicitly

```
return (jelly_beans, jars, crates)
```

The next part is called tuple unpacking

```
sometuple = secret_formula(start_point)
beans, jars, crates = sometuple
```

since your function returns a tuple of 3,it can be unpacked to 3 variables

you can also do this in one step

```
beans, jars, crates = secret_formula(start_point)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
formula = secret_formula(start_point)
print type(formula)  # <type 'tuple'>
```

So when you are returning its `return` a tuple.

```
beans, jars, crates = secret_formula(start_point)
```

by this you are initialising these variables with data in `tuple` like this:-

```
In [6]: a, b, c = (1, 2, 3)

In [7]: a
Out[7]: 1

In [8]: b
Out[8]: 2

In [9]: c
Out[9]: 3
```

so if you do something like this even storing in a single variable it works fine,

```
print "We'd have {!r} formula" .format(formula)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def secret_formula(started):
    jelly_beans = started * 500
    jars = jelly_beans / 1000
    crates = jars / 100
    return jelly_beans, jars, crates

start_point = 10000
beans, jars, crates = secret_formula(start_point)

print "With a starting point of: %d" % start_point
print "We'd have %d beans, %d jars, and %d crates." % (beans, jars, crates)
```

breakdown:

1. Define start_point as 10,000
2. Pass that into secret_formula()
3. Inside secret_formula is a new 'scope' - a place where variables can exist. It's like being in a house with one-way glass windows. You can see variables in the scope outside, but the outside cannot see in. {Scope exists in part so you can have different functions using the same variable names like `x` and `y` without clashes}.
4. In the secret_formula *scope*, create the variables `jelly_beans` and `jars` and `crates` and do calculations, and link (*bind*) the resulting numbers to those names.
5. Inside secret_formula, combine these three into a `tuple`. That's what `jelly_beans, jars, crates` is doing by having them with commas between them. A tuple is a collection of a few things grouped together and treated as one thing for convenience. You can only return one thing, so this is a workaround to return three-numbers-as-one-thing. The tuple contains the *numbers*, not the *names*.
6. Inside secret_formula, return the tuple and finish.
7. Python clears up the secret_formula *scope* and removes the `jelly_beans` and `jars` and `crates` *names* that were running inside it somewhen around now. The function is no longer running and all the names used inside it have "fallen out of scope" and get cleaned up.
8. The tuple coming out of the function is a group of three *numbers*, in order. Create three new variable names, split the three numbers up, and bind the numbers to those new names, in *this* outer scope.

> Does this mean that jelly_beans, jars, crates from the return can be replaced with any combo of three?

Yep. NB. When `print` prints "%d" it's looking for a whole number, so you would have to replace them with any three numbers `3,55,100` or number variables.

Answer (score 0):

One interesting difference between python with other languages such as java and C# is python can return several results, that is what we called tuple

So to your question:
Does this mean that jelly_beans, jars, crates from the return can be replaced with any combo of three?

My answer is yes,

after the code: the three variable would be initialized, and know the type of themselves...

```
beans, jars, crates = secret_formula(start_point)
```

if the secret_formula() function returns as:

```
return 1, 'a', {'key':'value'}
```

that also make senses, beans, jars, crates will know they are int, string and dict type respectively

Comment: sorry, yes it is dict :)